# Set cardinality exercise mistake in a textbook?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, cardinals

During studying set cardinality, I came across on this exercise:

$$2{}^{\aleph_0}2 = {}^{\aleph_0}2 + {}^{\aleph_0}$$

I understand that ${}^{\aleph_0}2$ is just $2^{\aleph_0}$ written in this way, at least previous text implies it. But I am really confused about what $^{\aleph_0}$ is supposed to be as there is no explanation for it whatsoever. There is a solution to the excercise, but it uses the same notation and therefore I do not understand it, even if it's quite short.

I think it's some typographical mistake, but having only brief background in cardinality, I can't figure out what the equation means. I bet it's either meant to be $2^{\aleph_0}$ or simply ${\aleph_0}$. Could you please find an explanation of this typo or post a meaningful version of the equation?

P.S. The textbook is in Slovak, so I won't post the solution here. Though I will translate it if it's necessary.

Comment: Looks like a typo to me.  It's hard to guess what was intended without more context.  Can you show some of the context?

Comment: It could be related to infinity, $\aleph_0$ is sometimes used for the smallest infinite cardinal I think. Also, this seems to be a notation question I'll add that tag. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elvOZm0d4H0  and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7c2qz7sO0I&list=PLa6IE8XPP_glwNKmFfl2tEL0b7E9D0WRr&index=27  talk about infinity,  and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrU9YDoXE88 talks about what's called aleph null.

Comment: I think the book's intention was $2\cdot {}^{\aleph_0}2={}^{\aleph_0}2+{}^{\aleph_0} 2. $

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I highly doubt that's the issue.

Comment: Something seems missing from the displayed equation.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, that's the purpose of this question.

Comment: What does ${}^{\aleph_0}$ even mean on its own?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I do not know, I suppose it's a mistake in the textbook. I posted this question in order to figure out what is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have concluded that the stated equation really is a mistake in the textbook and that the intention was to write $2{}^{\aleph_0}2 = {}^{\aleph_0}2 + {}^{\aleph_0}2$ as Mr. Caicedo pointed out.